# For loop displaying incorrect information stored inside array

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have this really simple program, with a `for` loop designed to run 3 times.

For every iteration, it will ask the user to enter in the weather. Each time, the user's input is stored in an integer array called `C`.

Once the loop concludes, I have another `for` loop that print's out the user's input.  This next loop works fine for the 2 values, but gives off some weird messed up value once it reaches the third iteration.

```
int main(){
    
    //Variable declaration:
    int days;
    int C[2];
    int F[2];
    
    for(days=0; days<3; days++){
        cout << "What is the temperature in celsius for day " << days + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cin >> C[days];
        F[days] = (C[days] * 9/5) + 32;
    }
    
    cout << "\nCelsius\t\t Farenheit\n-------\t\t ---------" << endl;
    for(days =0; days <3; days++){
        cout << C[days] << "\t\t " << F[days] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Recant...`C[days]` is initialized in the `cin` statement.

Comment: `int C[2];`, `for(...; days < 3; ...)` do you see a problem here?

Comment: thanks guys, I see the problem!

Answer (score 3):

> This next loop works fine for the 2 values but gives off some weird messed up value once it reaches the third iteration.

Your definition of `C` states it has 2 entries, but your loop runs for
three iterations (0, 1, and 2).

Comment: thanks I see what went wrong, appreciate the answer!

Comment: [More info here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/). `the elements field (which is always enclosed in square brackets []), specifies the length of the array in terms of the number of elements.` So in other words, `int foo[5]`'s only valid indices are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.